# Update sprite position when speed changes if frame rate is low

Tags: c#, xna, physics

I have a sprite moving horizontally from left to right. For each iteration I want to start decreasing the speed.
This works ok, and the sprite will stop at some point, however depending on the frame rate it won't always stop 
at the same place. What's wrong with my code?

```
...
Vector2 Position;
Vector2 Speed;
...
Speed.X = 50;
...

public override void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
{
    float time = (float) theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    Position += Speed * time;

    Speed.X-=10; // Reduce speed for next iteration
    if ( Speed.X < 0 ) Speed.X = 0;
}
```

I have also tried by doing

```
Speed.X-=10 * time;
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
Speed.X-=10;
```

This decreases the speed by a constant amount, so a lower framerate will mean less speed loss in the same amount of time. You touch on this in your second attempt:

```
Speed.X-=10 * time;
```

While the character will indeed stop after five seconds with this iteration, he still might spend more time at higher speeds with a lower framerate. For example, a 10 FPS framerate will cause him to spend 0.1 seconds each at speeds of 10, 9, 8, etc. A 2 FPS framerate will cause him to spend 0.5 seconds at 10 speed and 0.5 seconds at 5 speed.

What you need to do is take the average velocity over the frame and displace the player along that velocity for the given frame time. I'm not familiar with C#, so I'll give some pseudocode that may or may not be proper syntax throughout:

```
float time = (float) theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
float startFrameSpeed = Speed.X;
float endFrameSpeed = Speed.X - (10 * time);

float displacement = 0;

if(endFramespeed < 0) {
    //This is a problem because the player ends the frame with negative speed and that will throw off our average. We need to calculate the displacement a bit differently in this instance.

    //If you change the speed change from 10 units per second, you'll need to replace these tens with the new value. I would thus recommend storing the step in a variable for quick adjustment later.

    float timeSpentWithNegativeSpeed = -(endFrameSpeed / 10); //Get a positive value for time.
    displacement = 10 * timeSpentWithNegativeSpeed;
}

//Displace the player along the average speed throughout the frame.
Position += (startFrameSpeed + endFrameSpeed) / 2 + displacement;
Speed.X = endFrameSpeed;

if(Speed.X < 0) Speed.X = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! That was exactly what I needed to make it work. Regards

Comment: No problem! It's always a pleasure to help a fellow developer!